# Return value from Cell Name or reference

Tags: excel, cell

I have the sheets below with what I exactly require.

I have a Table with number of names from `A1:A5`. In `D2` I have entered a cell reference as `A2`, then I need to show the `A2` cell value in cell `E2`

[image: cell reference]

Comment: In E2   put `=INDIRECT(D2)`  FYI - your description doesn't match your screenshot.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Its Really working. changes made on screenshot also.